# React Native : FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: react-native

Error images;

https://resmim.net/preview/qktxgY.png

sdk ;

27.0.0 
 27.0.1
 27.0.2
 27.0.3
 28.0.3

Emulator open I've installed them, but I get an error like this.

---

> **Solution ;**
>
> ```
> ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin
> ```
>
> Run the sdkmanager as follows:
>
> ```
> ./sdkmanager --licenses
> ```
>
> press Y to confirm the license

Comment: did you accept the license of SDK? the error says you didn't

Comment: I don't know how to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Android Studio? If not, it's best to get it and download specific SDK packages from there. You'll need to go to your preferences/settings and go to what it looks like here: [image: androidStudio.png]

Be sure to check `Show Package Details` to get the specific packages you need. Some good info is also on the RN Docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started#android-development-environment).

Comment: Android Studio is already installed. I have installed all sdk packages but I keep getting this error.

Comment: You might need to try to reinstall them. It'll try and have you accept the license when you do.